# How do I get Typescript to be happy with turning a string into a HTML Element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a generic Button component in react.

To help keep things generic, I want to be able to choose what Element is used to render the button. Whether that be a standard HTML button, an anchor element or a span. This is passed into the component props as a string. ButtonProps is below:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  component?: string;
  variant: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'default' | 'text';
  children: JSX.Element | string;
  classes?: string;
};
```

I'm then setting the default value of the component prop to 'button'. And trying to render:

```
/**
 *
 * Stateless component for buttons
 * @export
 * @param {ButtonProps} props
 */
export default function Button(props: ButtonProps): JSX.Element {
  const { component = 'button', classes = clsx(), children } = props;
  const ComponentProp = component;
  return <ComponentProp>{children}</ComponentProp>;
}
```

TypeScript gives the error `Type '{ children: string | Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`

How do I appease TS? Or is this just a stupid way to be doing things?

Comment: Not all elements have children, but your code assumes they do. I think the types are trying to tell you that.

Comment: Let type inference work for you.